# Regular expression to find all occurences of new [] operator in c++

Tags: regex

I would like to search my Visual Studio C++ Project for array version of new operator e.g.

```
some_type some_variable = new my_name [some_size];
```

I tried this but it doesn't work:

```
new [a-zA-Z0-9]+ \[
```

How can I achieve this with regex ?

Comment: Read up on regex. Shouldn't get too complicated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to allow all valid identifier characters in your character class (the `[a-zA-Z0-9]+` part). In your example, you have an underscore, for instance. Also, you might want to make the space between the identifier and the brackets optional.

Try this:

```
new [A-Za-z0-9_]+\s*\[
```

But check the specifications regarding exactly what characters are valid for `my_name`